# Pyramid that cannot 3d print because its different in Blender / print software

Tags: modeling, mesh

I have remade my pyramid in blender 4 times now, becoming an expert, but my pyramid has the top cut off, it is a hollow pyramid with the top cut off

When I load it into the STL format, Blender saves the whole pyramid, including its GHOST top when there are no visible vertices or edges too allow the top too exist.

Comment: Solved my own problem thankyou. - by doing it differently. - i didnt really solve it !!

Answer (score 2):

every 3model you want to 3D print should be closed (watertight), so your piramid should have thick walls, and not single layer faces. That would solve your ghost tip problem as well